# Why is the 'E' terminal connected on my thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I'm trying to update my Honeywell TH4210D1005 thermostat to a nest thermostat. On researching the Honeywell thermostat, it seems to be designed for systems with heat pumps? Further, it does have the E terminal wired up
[image]

However, I am pretty sure my current HVAC unit(Ameristar M4AH3042B1000AA with condenser M4AC3043B1000NA) doesn't have a heat pump. I dug up it's installation [manual](https://ameristarhvac.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/M4AC3-Air-Conditioner-Installation-Manual.pdf) and it's wiring scheme and they don't mention anything about the E terminal either.
[image]

Almost seems like someone wired the W2 on my HVAC to the E terminal. Can someone help me make sense of what's going on here

Here's the photos from my furnace/air handler.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit :- NVM turns out my apartment does have a heat pump. Looked it up from the apartment sale listing. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Where do all the ducts in your house go?

Comment: Added photos for the wiring at the furnace.

Comment: In your last photo, which cable goes to which piece of equipment?